# Z axis in isometric tilemap

Tags: html5, isometric, html-canvas

I'm experimenting with isometric tile maps in JavaScript and HTML5 Canvas.
I'm storing tile map data in JavaScript 2D array.

```
// 0 - Grass
// 1 - Dirt
// ...
var mapData = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    ...
]
```

and draw

```
for(var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < mapData[i].length; j++) {
        var p = iso2screen(i, j, 0); // X, Y, Z
        context.drawImage(tileArray[mapData[i][j]], p.x, p.y);
    }
}
```

but this function mean's all tile Z axis is equal to zero.

```
var p = iso2screen(i, j, 0);
```

Maybe anyone have idea and how to do something like `mapData[0][0]` Z axis equal to `3` `mapData[5][5]` Z axis equal to `5`?

I have idea: Write function for grass, dirt and store this function to 2D array and draw and later `mapData[0][0].setZ(3);` But it is good idea to write functions for each tiles?

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear. Instead of saying "do something like..." Can you tell us what you want to do? I don't know how you're going to call `.setZ(3)` on an integer stored in an array.

Comment: .setZ(3) work if I'm create functions for each tiles and create "setZ" method, but maybe is other method when create functions for all tiles?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by Z axis we're kind of talking about the 'height' of the tile here.

If you're sure that there would only ever be one tile on each of the X and Y axes (like a heightmap) then you can just modify your map array to store two values rather than a number:

```
// mapData[i][j][0] is the tile Id, mapData[i][j][1] is the Z axis
var mapData = [
    [[0,0], [0,1], [0,0], [0,2], [0,3]],
    [[0,1], [0,0], [1,0, [0,1], [0,2],
    ...
]
```

If you're not sure of this (i.e, you might have caves or overhangs or similar features) then the way to do it is **slices**.

Slices are all the same size (the whole of your map) and you would have one for each and every Z level possible. You would also require a new tile type of 'Nothing', which means you just don't draw anything.

This way is more expensive, but if you need the flexibility it's the way to do it.